Python S3 streaming, return stream from function
Is it possible to return an open write stream from a function?
I am getting the error:

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

import boto3
import io

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Download file from S3 and upload a copy

def download_s3():
    response = s3.get_object(
        Bucket="bedrock-data-files", 
        Key="test/filename.txt"
        )
    stream = io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read())
    return stream

def upload_s3():
    returnedStream = io.BytesIO()
    s3.upload_fileobj(
        returnedStream,
        "bedrock-data-files", 
        "test/copy.txt"
        )
    return returnedStream

downloadstream = download_s3()
uploadstream = upload_s3()
for chunk in downloadstream.read():
    uploadstream.write(chunk)

This version works, but I need the write stream to be created in a function.
def download_s3():
    response = s3.get_object(
        Bucket="bedrock-data-files", 
        Key="test/filename.txt"
        )
    stream = io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read())
    return stream

downloadstream = download_s3()
print(downloadstream) # This line returns <_io.BytesIO object at 0x10679dbc0>
s3.upload_fileobj(
    downloadstream,
    "bedrock-data-files", 
    "test/copy.txt"
    )


Your call to io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read()) in your download_s3 function reads all the data from the stream and returns a bytes object, not a stream.

I see, so how should I do it? When I leave off the read() it says "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'StreamingBody'". I have successfully run a version of the download_s3 function that just uses the stream in the calling function.

Sorry i have not used this class, I suggest you check the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#buffered-streams. There may be alternative methods that will do what you want.

I have been looking further at this class and think you should be able to do something like the following:
def download_s3():
    response = s3.get_object(
        Bucket="bedrock-data-files", 
        Key="test/filename.txt"
        )
    data = io.BytesIO(response['Body'])
    return data # this is a bytes object containing all the data from response['Body']

downloaddata = download_s3()
uploadstream = upload_s3()
N = 1024 # set N to the number of bytes to read
         # if N is omitted then read will return all the data on the first call
while True:
    chunk = downloaddata.read(N) # read the next chunk of data
    if len(chunk) == 0: # if nothing is returned
        break;          # then end of data has been reached
    uploadstream.write(chunk)


Thanks, but io.BytesIO still throws the error without the read() "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'StreamingBody'"

Unfortunately i have no way of reproducing your environment so it's difficult to suggest a lot. You could try adding the read() call back to io.BytesIO(response['Body']). If that does not work then you will need to do some further experimentation to find a method that returns a proper bytes object from the stream.

That is back tot he original error: "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

If I replace the uploadstream.write line with "print(chunk)" it does print the file contents as b'file contents' which I believe is a sequence of bytes. So I don't think the problem is in download_s3 or the copying loop. I think the problem is that returning the stream from upload_s3 is somehow closing it, or something.

You can check that by examining the object returned from upload_s3. That needs to be a writable stream, but that is down to the s3.upload_fileobj function, which I do not know.

You are right about needing to give a byte count to read(), though. My second code sample, which "works", is actually holding the whole file in memory. I don't know how to make this work at all.

Sorry, but I think your problem is more likely with the AWS functions. Maybe try Amazon developer forums for help.
